# How to get multiple message IDs in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My bot sends 3 messages following eachother and I need to save their IDs, because I need to edit them later. If I do something like this:

```
message.channel.send(`${acc[player].output.slot1}`).then((m) => {
  acc[player].ids.msg1 = m.id
})
  
message.channel.send(`${acc[player].output.slot2}`).then((n) => {
  acc[player].ids.msg2 = n.id
})
    
message.channel.send(`${acc[player].output.slot3}`).then((o) => {
  acc[player].ids.msg3 = o.id
})
```

all three will have the 3rd one's ID. Slowing down the process or doing it step by step didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure all three have the same ID? They shouldn't have.

Comment: Did you tried saving all IDs in different variables? Also are you sure all three have the same ID?

Comment: These are different variables, and yes, they did get the same IDs.

Comment: Try console logging each id

Comment: Not sure how console logging the IDs could help, since they end up being the same in the json file and on discord too when the bot sends them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why all 3 entries would result in the same value, however maybe handling the promises differently could help. Try awaiting `Promise.all()` with an array of the send messages and map all the results to the id.

```js
const { send } = message.channel;

try {
   (await Promise.all([
      send(`${acc[player].slot1}`),
      send(`${acc[player].slot2}`),
      send(`${acc[player].slot3}`)
   ])).forEach((msg, i) => {
      acc.player.ids[`msg${i + 1}`] = msg.id;
   });
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong. You put `variable.["property"]`, you probably meant to put `variable["property"]`

Comment: Thanks, now  fixed